# Diferenciar el valor "undefined" de typeof de una variable inexistente del de una definida con el valor undefined

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

Tomemos un ejemplo:

```
    var a; //hereda el valor undefined automaticamente
    var b = undefined; //se le asigna el mismo valor pero manualmente

    //Si accedemos a los tipos
    console.log(typeof a);  //"undefined"
    console.log(typeof b);  //"undefined"
    console.log(typeof c);  //"undefined"

    //Si accedemos a los valores
    console.log(a);  //undefined
    console.log(b);  //undefined
    console.log(c);  //ERROR: c is not defined

    if(typeof c !== "undefined"){  //Si introduzco tanto a, como b o como c...
        console.log("La variable c SÍ ha sido definida");
    } else {
        console.log("La variable c NO ha sido definida"); //...el resultado siempre será este.
    }
```

Podemos observar que el operador `typeof` da el mismo trato tanto a una variable no definida (devolviendo `"undefined"`) como a una que ha sido definida pero con un valor undefined (devolviendo `"undefined"` también) independientemente si se le ha asignado ese valor manualmente o no.
Mi pregunta es: ¿como es posible diferenciar entre las que si estan definidas con un valor undefined asignado de las que no han estado definidas? Plasmada en el ejemplo: ¿Como lograr que me detecte que c no ha estado definida a diferencia de a y b, que si lo están pese a tener un valor undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La unica forma en que puedes verificar si una variable ha sido declarada, es conteniendola dentro de un `try/catch` esperando a que lanze `ReferenceError` al momento de acceder a la variable:

```js
try{
 c;
}catch(error){
  if(error.name === 'ReferenceError') {
   console.log("la variable 'c' no ha sido declarada");
  }
}
```

Si lanzo el error entonces es porque no esta declarada, de lo contrario es porque si lo esta.

Como ya habras notado el operador `typeof` no lanza un error sino que la trata como `undefined`. Aun tambien si se utilizara `window.c` o `window['c']`, esto retornaria `undefined` por igual:

```js
console.log(window.c);
console.log(window['c']);
```

---

**Actualizacion**

Estaba equivocado, si hay otras maneras de verifica si una variable fue declarada. Como sugiere [@Jose Hermosilla Rodrigo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6095/jose-hermosilla-rodrigo), utilizar [`hasOwnProperty(prop)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) también puede indicar si fue declarada o no una variable:

```js
if(window.hasOwnProperty('c')){
  console.log('variable c definida')
}
else{
 console.log('variable c no definida')
}
```

Ten encuenta que si necesitas saber si esta declarada dentro de una función, `hasOwnProperty` no te funcionara a menos que le indiques el contexto en el cual va a buscar la propiedad:

```js
var global = "variable global";

var fn = function(){
  console.log(this.hasOwnProperty('c'))
}

fn(); // 'false' porque no esta declarada dentro de la funcion fn

fn = function(){
  var c = '';
  console.log(this.hasOwnProperty('c'))
  console.log(this.global); // this representa window por lo que podemos acceder a las variables definidas en window
}

fn(); // 'false' tambien ya que this representa el objeto window

new fn(); // 'false, undefined' por igual debido a que 'c' no esta declarada en el contexto de la funcion fn, sino de forma privada y la variable global dara undefined debido a que no esta declarada en el contexto this

fn = function(){
  this.c = ''; // la agregamos al contexto de la funcion
  console.log(this.hasOwnProperty('c'))
}

new fn(); // como si esta declarada en el contxto de fn() entonces si es posible encontrar la variable 'c'
```

En resumen, tienes que asegurarte de que estas buscando en el contexto(objeto) correcto cuando utilices la función `hasOwnProperty`.

Tambien esta el operador `in` que verifica si el objeto tiene definido cierta  propiedad y se le aplica la misma regla del contexto que `hasOwnProperty`:

```js
console.log('c' in window)
```

Comment: `window. hasOwnProperty ('c')` o `'c' in window` también pueden valer.

Comment: Casi nunca me acuerdo de `hasOwnProperty` porque no utilizo javascript ya muy a menudo. Puedo agregar tus sugerencias a mi respuesta?

Comment: Por supuesto!! :)